# ionic window.open() give permission demied and window.addeventlistner didn't triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <div id="container">
    <strong>Ready to create an app?</strong>
    <p>Start with Ionic <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/components">UI Components</a></p>
    <div>
      <button (click)="onload()"> Hello window</button>
      </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Onload method linked with onload button from HTML.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {}
  onload(){
    var win = window.open( "http://docs.kendoui.com", "_blank", "EnableViewPortScale=yes" );
      win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
        console.log("hello world")
      setTimeout(function() {
          win.close();
      }, 5000 );
       });
  }
}
```

I m trying to print the hello world on loadstop event.
which should trigger but when i check console there is only one error permission denied and the event is not trigger.
I m just trying to open a window in-app and connect those using event listener .

Comment: In win.addeventlistner instead of function() use ()=> and instead of _blank use _system and then test and tell me if done